# delete a dynamic element of a 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I create a database of students, that allow user to add name of student and delete them. I want my array to be dynamic. The program run successfully in order to add a student to the database. But when I want to delete from database, in the display loop I have a memory access violation. I know that my program crash because I attempt to read a student that was deleted, but I don't know which condition I have to write in my loop in order to overpass this value that doesn't exist any more.

```
char** delete(char** database, int length, char* word)
{
    if (length)
    {
        char** temp = new char* [length];
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(*(database + i), word) != 0)
            {
                *(temp + i) = *(database + i);
            }
            else
            {
                delete database[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; temp[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
            {
                cout << temp[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

This is a part of my main function that correspond to what I want. lengthDb is a int var that tell size of the database.

```
char** database = NULL;
cout << "Enter the name of student to delete" << endl;
cin.getline(student, 50);
    lengthDb--;
    database = del(database, lengthDb, student);
```

Comment: Assign `nullptr` to the pointer after deletion, and check against that?

Comment: What do you return from `delete` if the length is `0`?

Comment: The use of raw pointers and even operator `new` is discouraged in modern C++. The use of C-style string constants is also discouraged.  Prefer `std::vector` to raw memory allocations, and prefer `std::string` to character arrays.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` -- Why are you not simply using this?

Comment: @Ron I have to do this with char, and old array